# Is order of evaluation sequential in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

At a job interview, I was perplexed to hear "javascript can evaluate statements out of order." To what degree is this true? I can imagine a hundred ways to explicitly evaluate statements out of order -- such as in a time-sharing operating system. But he *seemed* to say that if I evaluate

```
console.log('a')
console.log('b')
```

that the Javascript spec somehow doesn't require that the output would be `a` first then `b`. I can imagine that the evaluator might *try* to evaluate the second statement if the IO of the first is blocking if the statements are functionally pure, i.e. no side effects, but side effects must always occur in sequence, correct? And of course IO is one big side effect.

To what extent can spec-compliant Javascript evaluate out of order? Or was this a case of miscommunication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript is single threaded (web workers aside). Period. [ECMA-262 Language Specification  Edition 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) says nothing about out-of-order execution. In your simple example these two statements are *guaranteed* to be executed in the same order.

Moreover, single block of JavaScript code will never be interrupted by any other block of code, e.g. event  handler. That's why long running blocks of code cause UI to *freeze*:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

It's guaranteed that the block of code above will never be interrupted or reordered. As long as the loop is running, all event handlers and timeouts wait for single thread. And of course, numbers will appear in correct order.

What might be executed out-of-order is an asynchronous timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('a');
}, 1);
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('b');
}, 1);
```

Here you might expect `a` to be printed first, but it's possible that JS engine will reorder these events. After all you schedule these calls to execute at almost the same point in time.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think your asynchronous timeout example is correct. They will always be scheduled and run in the same order. Why would the JS engine reorder these events? They come right after one another when declaring them to run asynchronously at the same amount of time after being declared. It might be more controversial if you used real numbers for the timeout values and made them different - like `2001` for the first and `2000` for the second. If the second one weren't in a `setTimeout`, then it would definitely be run first (the confusing part). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ian: what makes you think "they will always be scheduled and run in the same order"?  AFAIK "setTimeout" isn't part of any official spec which would mandate such behavior.  Moreover, if the two calls happened in the same quantum (millisecond, microsecond, etc) why couldn't a browser put them in a data structure which doesn't maintain order but does ensure execution after the timeout period?

Comment: @maerics Good point, just something I didn't think about. At the same time, why wouldn't the engine order them as they came in? I guess since there's no spec for it, it is possible. At the same time, I would expect it to have common sense and as soon as it received something (for a specific time), it would be put in that queue. If it received another (for the same time), it would just be scheduled for right after any previous (in this case, only 1). Again, using `2001` and `2000` for timeout values makes sense to me as more of a controversy.

Comment: @maerics And I guess I don't know the timing of execution (how fast Javascript actually runs), but could these ever run in the same microsecond or millisecond?

Comment: @Ian: yes, absolutely, modern JS engines are very fast.  Anyway, it's likely that most JS interpreters behave as you suspect, I just wanted to point out that this is probably by practicality of implementation rather than by conformance to any specification.

Comment: @maerics Okay, I wasn't sure of the magnitude of speed. But of course, that's a very important thing to point out...one that I didn't know/wasn't sure about!

Answer (score 2):

Clearly miscommunication.

The dude was maybe referring to JavaScript hoisting. You can read more about it here : http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Furthermore, you can learn more particularities of the language here: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, yes. With two major exceptions (leaving aside the obvious "define a function, call the function" which effectively "goes back" to the function body):

1: Hoisting. `var` statements are hoisted, so if you write

```
alert(a);
var a = 123;
```

You get `undefined`, and not an error message. This is because it is hoisted to

```
var a;
alert(a);
a = 123;
```

Similarly, function definitions are hoisted too. If you write:

```
foo(123);
function foo(num) {alert(num);}
```

It will work, because the function is hoisted. However, this does NOT work if you wrote

```
foo(123);
foo = function(num) {alert(num);}
```

Because that's an assignment of an anonymous function, not a function definition.

2: Asynchronous functions.

A common mistake among beginners is to write this:

```
var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
a.open("GET","sompage.php",true);
a.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( a.readyState == 4 && a.status == 200) {
        myvar = "Done!";
    }
};
a.send();

alert(myvar);
```

They expect the alert to say `Done!`, but instead they get an inexplicable error about it not being defined. This is because the `myvar = "Done!"` hasn't been run yet, despite appearing earlier in the script.

---

See also this anecdote from [Computer Stupidities](http://www.rinkworks.com/stupid/cs_programming.shtml):

> An introductory programming student once asked me to look at his program and figure out why it was always churning out zeroes as the result of a simple computation. I looked at the program, and it was pretty obvious:
>
> ```
> begin
>  readln("Number of Apples", apples);
>  readln("Number of Carrots", carrots);
>  readln("Price for 1 Apple", a_price);
>  readln("Price for 1 Carrot", c_price);
>  writeln("Total for Apples", a_total);
>  writeln("Total for Carrots", c_total);
>  writeln("Total", total);
>  total := a_total + c_total;
>  a_total := apples * a_price;
>  c_total := carrots + c_price;
> end;
> ```
>
> - Me: "Well, your program can't print correct results before they're computed."
> - Him: "Huh? It's logical what the right solution is, and the computer should reorder the instructions the right way."

Answer (score 0):

I think they tried to put you on your wrong foot. Javascript is sequensial. Otherwise functions where you calculate values won't work out. What can be true is that `console.log` activates an `Async task` which means it can be executed in a different order. Like an `Ajax` call, a `Webworker`, a `timeout` or an `interval`.

If you do the following it will result B than A, this is not a sequensial code because in code. A comes for B but B is executed first.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("A")
}, 5);
console.log("B");
```